# ESLint capturou um erro, Parsing error: Unexpected token =

Tags: javascript, react, eslint

Olá, instalei o ESLint para capturar os erros e verificar o código, porém o mesmo está pegando esse erro na linha 28 "updateDay = () => {" onde o problema está nessa sintax com o = antes do (), mas eu não sei qual seria a sintax correta nesse caso, pois ainda sou iniciante em Js.

Esse é o código de erro:

> 28:15  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token =

```
updateDay = () => {
    const date = new Date();
    this.setState({
        currentDate: date.getDate(),
        weekday: getWeekdayAsString(date),
    });
};
```

Aqui está o código completo

```
import React from 'react';

import { getWeekdayAsString } from '../utils/dateTimeUtils';

class WeatherDisplay extends React.Component {   
    constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      temperature: 22,
      degrees: 'c',
      forecast: 'parcialmente-nublado',
      weekday: 'Hoje',
      currentDate: null,
    };   }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.timerID = setInterval(() => this.updateDay(), 1000);   }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.timerID);   }

  updateDay = () => {
    const date = new Date();
    this.setState({
        currentDate: date.getDate(),
        weekday: getWeekdayAsString(date),
    });
};

  render() {
    const {
      temperature,
      degrees,
      forecast,
      weekday,
      currentDate,
    } = this.state;

    const icone = `/imgs/${forecast}.svg`;

    return (
      <div className="weather-display">
        <div className="weather-now">
          <img className="icon" src={icone} alt={forecast} />
          <span className="temperature">{temperature}
            <span className="degree">º{degrees}</span>
          </span>
        </div>
        <span className="weekday">{weekday} {currentDate}</span>
      </div>
    );   } }

export default WeatherDisplay;
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42701804/1377664

Comment: Em que contexto está esse código? o que vem antes de `updateDay`? O que é updateDay? uma `var`, `let`, `const`?

Comment: Isso não estará dentro de uma classe ?

Comment: fiz uma atualização no post com o código completo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parece-me que estás a tentar usar uma "Arrow Function expression", estas devem ser feitas agarradas a um scope, pex:

```
const functionName = () => console.log('hello from functionName');
```

Estas funções são funçoes anonimas que são declaradas com a ajuda de uma variavel (no caso do exemplo, a constate "functionName")

Se quiseres usar uma "Arrow Function statement" podes usar assim:

```
functionName() { console.log('hello from functionName'; }
```

estas funções são funçoes com nomes que são, normalmente, declaradas em `Object`os e `Class`es, pex:

```
Class ClassName {
    functionNAme() { console.log('hello from functionName'; }
}
```

que depois seria usado com:

```
const className = new ClassName();
className.functionName()
```

---

O que o ESLint te está a dizer, neste caso, é que a syntax não está à espera de um `=` nessa posição, uma vez que não tens um scope atrás do nome da função, ele está à espera que essa função seja do tipo "arrow function statement" ao invés de "arrow function expression".

Answer (score 1):

Provavelmente o código da pergunta esta localizado dentro de uma classe como uma "static property", como abaixo:

```
class Something {
  updateDay = () => {
    const date = new Date();
    this.setState({
      currentDate: date.getDate(),
      weekday: getWeekdayAsString(date),
    });
  };
  render() { // seu codigo de renderização }
}
```

Se esse for o caso, essa sintaxe usa o conceito de "static class properties" que é parte do padrão es7 (e nao do es6), e portanto ainda não suportado pelo eslint sem a ajuda de um plugin.

Em outras palavras, voce precisara editar suas configurações do eslint para que o mesmo trabalhe com o parser "babel-eslint" para que o eslint faça as verificações após o codigo ter sido transpilado pelo babel (o que ira converter a sintaxe da "static property" em uma função cuja sintaxe o eslint sera capaz de interpretar corretamente).

Experimente instalar o babel-eslint com:

```
npm install babel-eslint --save-dev
```

E, após isso, editar o arquivo .eslintrc adicionando a seguinte linha:

```
{
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  ...
}
```

Fonte: https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/issues/589

Answer (score 0):

Tenha certeza de que o local onde declarou a function esteja dentro da classe do componente em questão e fora de outra function. Exemplo de erro comum:

```
render() {

    updateDay = () => {
        const date = new Date();
        this.setState({
            currentDate: date.getDate(),
            weekday: getWeekdayAsString(date),
        });
    };

    return(<div></div>)

}
```

Comment: está dentro da classe, porém fora de outras funções. Fiz uma alteração onde eu coloco todo o código.